# OpenAPI v3 / Swagger - calling a function and sending json dictionary to it

Tags: swagger, flask-sqlalchemy, openapi, connexion

I'm trying to use [OpenAPI/Swagger](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/) to run an endpoint capable of consuming a json dictionary, sending to a function and getting a response.

I'm using `operationId` to refer to the function that I want to call, but can't work out how to send the dictionary that's received by the endpoint.

`controllers.get_options` is called, but no parameters are sent to it with my current approach.

I think I'm missing something obvious, but it's not apparent!

I would call the endpoint like this:

```sh
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://localhost:8080/getoptions' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "product_area": "Main",
  "product_type": "New"
}'
```

This is the openapi config file (`./openapi.yaml`)

EDIT: adding `x-body-name: DiscussionResult` below solved the issue as per Helen's comment

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Test
  version: '1.0'
paths:
  /getoptions:
    post:
      description: Return product options from product type and area
      operationId: controllers.get_options
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            x-body-name: DiscussionResult
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/DiscussionResult'
      responses:
        200:
          description: "success"

components:
  schemas:
    DiscussionResult:
      type: object
      discriminator:
        propertyName: product_type
      properties:
        product_type:
          type: string
          example: "New"
        product_area:
          type: string
          example: "Main"
```

I'm running it using `connexion` as shown here:

`main.py`

```py
import connexion
import logging

def create_app():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    connex_app = connexion.FlaskApp(__name__, specification_dir="./openapi/")
    connex_app.add_api("./openapi.yaml", resolver_error=501)
    return connex_app


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = create_app()
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

`requirements.txt`

```
connexion[swagger-ui]
connexion>=2.2.0
python-jose[cryptography]
six>=1.9
Flask>=0.10.1
sqlathanor
```

and this is the function that I want to call

```py
def get_options(DiscussionResult):
    msg = "{} {}".format(DiscussionResult['product_area'], DiscussionResult['product_type'])
    return jsonify(message=msg), 200
```

Comment: How are you running the application? What are you getting when you call it? Maybe if you share a bit more code, then we might be able to replicate and find something.

Comment: added some more detail in description

Comment: Sadly I'm not experienced with connexion and I know I'm not helping with the question but.. is connexion an obligatory? I feel like Fastapi might be more suitable and easier to understand. Can make a little demo which fits the needs.

Comment: Thanks. I could possibly switch to Fastapi, I would have thought that `controllers.get_options` would still need to be called in a similar way though?

Comment: https://connexion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/request.html: _"In the OpenAPI 3.x.x spec, the `requestBody` does not have a name. By default it will be passed in as `‘body’`. You can optionally provide the `x-body-name` parameter in your `requestBody` schema to override the name of the parameter that will be passed to your handler function."_ See also https://github.com/zalando/connexion/issues/1241#issuecomment-876128903. Does this help?

Comment: That was it, I've referenced your comment in my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connexion docs on [Request Handling](https://connexion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/request.html) include the following note:

> In the OpenAPI 3.x.x spec, the requestBody does not have a name. By default it will be passed in as ‘body’. You can optionally provide the `x-body-name` parameter in your requestBody `schema` to override the name of the parameter that will be passed to your handler function.

Looks like you need to add `x-body-name: DiscussionResult` to the `DiscussionResult` schema that is used in the `requestBody`:

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    DiscussionResult:
      x-body-name: DiscussionResult   # <---------
      type: object
      ...
```

or

```yaml
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              x-body-name: DiscussionResult   # <---------
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/DiscussionResult'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd very much recommend FastApi as I already said in the comments earlier. Here is a little bit of a working code.

*main.py*

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()


class DetailsModel(BaseModel):
    product_area: str
    product_type: str


@app.post("/get_details")
async def _(
        input_json: DetailsModel
):
    return {"returns": input_json.dict()}
```

Run `uvicorn main:app --reload` from root directory

Then check http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs

Then you can call:

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://127.0.0.1:8000/get_details' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "product_area": "Main",
  "product_type": "New"
}'
```

Fastapi checks for any unprocessable entities with Pydantic which helps a lot with any requests that doesn't fit the model.
Check the official and very detailed documentation too https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/.